# Проблема с открытием файла (Qt)

Tags: qt, c++

**UPD:**

```
class CsvReader: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT        
private:
    QFile _file;
    ...
}
```

По порядку:

1. Создаю экземпляр CsvReader
2. Задаю имя файла для _file:

   `_file.setFileName(name);`
3. Открываю файл:

.

```
if(!_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    const char* msg = "File is imposible to open!";
    emit display_dialog(msg, false, true);
    qDebug(_file.fileName().toAscii());
    qDebug(" - File is imposible to open!\n");
    return false;
}
```

При этом он не открывается, в выводе приложения:

```
QFile::open: File (D:/QtProjects/foils_build/naca_1.csv) already open
D:/QtProjects/foils_build/naca_1.csv
 - File is imposible to open!
```

Что не так делаю?

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Дайте весь код, касающийся создания и открытия _file. Но в любом случае, текст ошибки говорит сам за себя: либо файл держит какой-нибудь ваш "блокнот" и не даёт открыть его кому-то ещё, либо вы открываете в своём коде дважды.

Comment: Насчёт блокнота вы загнули по-моему :)  Скорее всего, он где-то открывается или открывается, но не закрывается: вроде бы для открытого QFile можно поменять путь к файлу.

Comment: Кроме как в программе файл нигде не открывался. В коде открывается в единственном месте.

Answer (score 3):

Решено.

Не обратил внимание на конструктор CsvReader:

```
CsvReader::CsvReader(QObject *parent, const QString& file_name): QObject(parent),     _file(file_name), _separator(';')
{}
```

Именно там (`_file(file_name)`) файл и открывался первый раз. Простая невнимательность.

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать заменить ваш код работы с `QFile` на, например, работу с дефолтным `C++` стримом и посмотреть, что из этого получится.

*Также внимательно отнеситесь к механике работы `setFileName`:*

```
void QFile::setFileName ( const QString & name )
```

`Sets the name of the file. The name can have no path, a relative path, or an absolute path.` **`Do not call this function if the file has already been opened.`**

---

Вполне вероятно, что где-то ваши вызовы `open` и `setFileName` происходят не совсем так, как вы ожидали.

Comment: Интереса ради можно попробовать без QFile обойтись. Но хотелось бы все под одну гребенку. По поводу setFileName - вызов непосредственно перед open. Так ведь должно быть?

Comment: @decodder Попробуйте на стримах, причины-то разные могут быть. Может быть, все-таки, где-то еще происходит доступ к вашему файлу. *Не могу точно сказать.*

Comment: Попробую =)